# show/hide dropdown menu depending on radio button selection - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a form with 2 radio buttons and 2 drop down menus which works.
however i have now added another 2 radio buttons and 2 more drop down menus ( i have not changed the jquery) so it is not working.

i have uploaded it to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbawh/

what do I need to change in the jquery for both radio buttons and dropdowns to work.

what the form should do is:
if 'no' is selcted on 1 i want the dropdown to be greyed out. if 'yes' is selected users can select from dropdown. I want both to work independtly.

Comment: Your code there is a bit messy, I'll look into it. But, I don't quite understand what you want to do. When you click "NO" both select should be disabled?

Comment: thanks no they both work independtly. if no is selected in the 1st radio box they first 2 dropdowns should be greyed out. yet if i was to select yes in the 2nd radio box i would be able to select values from dropdown. I would also like to add that the name of the radio buttons, or drop down menus cannot be changed as they are linked to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

In html, radio buttons work as a group when they have the same `name` attribute. So by giving all four of your radio buttons the same `name` you've set them up as a single group (so clicking any of the four will deselect the previously select one). To fix this simply give the second Yes/No buttons some other `name`. Given that your select elements have names "colour1" and "colour2" you might like to rename the first Yes/No radios to "discount1" and the second set to "discount2".

Then update your jQuery code to use the new `name` that you've given to the second group of radios.

Your html in the fiddle is invalid in that you have tr and td elements that don't belong to a table, but in a general sense if you can put the first two radios and their associated select elements inside the same parent container (whether a tr or a div or something) it makes it easier to write simple jQuery code.

For example, if you fix your html to have the radios and their associated selects in the same table row you can then assign a single `.click()` handler to *all* the radios (even though they're in different groups) that will enable/disable only the select elements in the same table row by using jQuery to find the ones that belong to the same parent row:

```
$('input[name^="discount"]').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', this.value=='No');
});
```

This uses the [`^=` attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to put a `.click` handler on all inputs with a name starting with "discount". When clicked, it will then find the closet parent tr element and get all the select elements in that row and disable/enable them.

Comment: I cannot give my Yes/No buttons some other name as it is linked to mysql and have the same field name. Could I give it a different ID instead but keep the name the same?

Comment: No. The way radio buttons are grouped in html is by name so separate groups must have separate names. If there will only ever be two choices per group you could replace each set of two radios with a single checkbox and then you could give them the same name. Or you could give the radios names unrelated to your database fields and instead create a hidden input for each radio group where the hidden input would have the correct name and clicking the buttons would set the appropriate value in the hidden input.

Comment: @user - the radios can all have the same name if each group is contained in a different `<form>` element.

Comment: Good point @gilly3, though in this case I think the idea is to submit everything as a single form.

Answer (score 0):

In first place, you must be change the name of the second radio button group, thats all for radio buttons. Now for dropdowns:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
       if($(this).val()=='No'){
          if($(this).attr('name')=='discount'){
             $('#colour1,#shade1').attr('disabled',true);
          } else{
             $('#colour2,#shade2').attr('disabled',true);
          }
       } else {
          if($(this).attr('name')=='discount'){
             $('#colour1,#shade1').removeAttr('disabled');
          } else{
             $('#colour2,#shade2').removeAttr('disabled');
          }
       }
    });
});
```

That's work for do not change your HTML. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: thanks but syntax line 20: if($(this).attr('name' =='discount'){

Answer (score 0):

You should give different names to the radio buttons if you want to group them separately. Accordingly change the code in `validate` method.

I have fixed your issue in the fiddle take a look.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/qbawh/2/)**

Comment: @user1191294 - Take a look at this.

Comment: you my sir are the man. I need to do the same thing for 3,4,5. I (you) have already done 1 & 2,

Comment: sorry was just putting it on my webpage there. it works but the validation for the 2nd radio box/dropdown does not work. 

any idea why?

Comment: I have fixed it take a look here..There is a small change in the submit button click handler. http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/qbawh/2/

Comment: awesome you have helped me greatly thanks. I will mark this answer. Can you check if I am doing it right for the rest 3-5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155181/show-hide-3-5-sets-of-dropdown-menu-depending-on-radio-button-selection-jquery

Comment: The script which I have will work for any number of elements. If you increase the elements you dont have to repeat the script. It is dynamic so will take care of any number of elements.

Comment: i have just discovered that it is not working in firefox. do you know the reason for this. I thought jquery was compatible with all broswers?

Comment: I have also just discovered after alot of troubleshotting that when the input type on my submit button is changed to 'button' it does NOT save info to mysql but validation works. If i change it to input type to 'submit' it saves info to mysql but the validation does not work :S. Is there a resolution to this?