# show/hide 3-5 sets of dropdown menu depending on radio button selection - jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using the same setup for the 3rd radio box / drop down im going to name it discount 3, colour 3, shade3 ect. can you check if i am going the right way about it for 3,4,5

http://jsfiddle.net/PP8h2/

Comment: It would help if your example was valid.

Comment: please don't post another thread regarding the same problem when you have other users trying to solve it there with you having not flag any of the answers there as useful/correct.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154491/show-hide-dropdown-menu-depending-on-radio-button-selection-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer this question without knowing the context. Your fiddle is also incomplete. You have not included the required markup and jQuery library in it.

Since I have answered the previous question related to this here is the working fiddle with 5 rows of input radio buttons and select elements with complete validation.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/PP8h2/1/)**